# How to add an image through URL to arcgis story map?

Tags: story-map

I want to add an image to my arcgis story map by Url.
I am having an error while i am uploading my image.

[image]

How to add an image to my argis story map by using URL method?

Comment: What is the URL of the image that you are trying to use?

Comment: https://goo.gl/photos/c7qb9ae3CmQDVAPh8

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/t3g3y6halw6odja/Paragliding%20Club%20Thermique.jpg?dl=0

Comment: Please always include errors as text rather than pictures

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know much about ArcGIS Story Map, but I do know that for Dropbox you want to use a slightly different URL to get the image directly.

You are using:

```
https://www.dropbox.com/s/t3g3y6halw6odja/Paragliding%20Club%20Thermique.jpg?dl=0
```

But you should use:

```
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/t3g3y6halw6odja/Paragliding Club Thermique.jpg?dl=0
```

Probably replacing the spaces with %20, but you get what I mean.

Answer (score 3):

You are using URLs that link to the page that holds the photo. ArcGIS expects a link directly to the photo file instead.

For the Google hosted picture, you can get it like this:

1. Open the album page you linked (https://goo.gl/photos/c7qb9ae3CmQDVAPh8)
2. Click the photo to open it.
3. Right-click on the photo and select the option "Copy Image Address" (Chrome) or "Copy Image  Location" (Firefox).
   Paste this into the box and it will work.

For Dropbox see Mark Ireland's answer.

Answer (score 2):

The error message says that your image URLs should start with http:// but your two examples, in comments, both start with https://.

I use Flickr to host the images I use with Story Maps and they work fine.

Comment: Also i tried with http. How about if i want add them by url?

Comment: How to know my flickr Id?

Answer (score 2):

Another option [suggested here](http://cantonbecker.com/etcetera/2014/how-to-directly-link-or-embed-dropbox-images/) is to add `?raw=1` in place of `?dl=0`:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/t3g3y6halw6odja/Paragliding%20Club%20Thermique.jpg?raw=1

This opens the image in a new empty browser tab and not in the Dropbox download window.